# Output SCSS in to two CSS files instead of one to get around IE9 and below selector quantity

Tags: css, sass

I am outputting in to app.css all of the foundation scss files, so there is one big css file styling the website.

There are too many selectors, about 5000+ and I believe that becuase it's over the 4096 that you are allowed for IE9 and below, some of the styles aren't being output.

How can I compile in to two separate CSS files, app.css and app1.css to make the styles work in IE9 and below?

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228459/count-number-of-selectors-in-a-css-file

Comment: Take a look at this blog post: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/09/splitting-long-css-files-to-overcome-ie9-4095-rules-limit/